# ng-submit doesn't fire the event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, onclicklistener, ng-submit

I'm stuck with this simple form submission. I feel that everything is right, but it doesn't work.

My **html** :

```
<html ng-app = 'myApp'>      
<div ng-controller="Tabs">  
...

       <form ng-submit="sendClicked()" >
          <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="text"/>

             <span class="input-group-btn" >
                 <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">SEND</button>
             </span>
          </div>
       </form>
  ...
</div>
</html>
```

My **app.js** :

```
myApp.controller('Tabs', function ($scope) {

    $scope.sendClicked = function () {
        console.log('can reach here');
        if($scope.text) {
                socket.emit('send message', $scope.text);
                $scope.text = null;
        }
    };

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be **input type submit**, but you have button, that doesn't ever have **type** attribute property

Comment: Changed that but still same result.

Comment: Check twice, be sure name of method is correct in angular controller, remove span wrapper and etc

Comment: here is the plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/DdCkNPC1ZZnbIxHvHsJQ?p=preview I did the same. Any help?

Comment: in the plunkr you posted you are missing ui boostrap and angular references which causes that to fail. added angular and remove ui boostrap from the module it all works. http://plnkr.co/edit/uKGlqMO71x1v6vN7bAG7?p=preview

Comment: You didn't attach angular